# MySQL/PHP ordering Danish letters

Tags: php, mysql

How come I don't get the list ordered properly? I have done as follows (the tagname field is set to utf8_danish_ci):

```
SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY tagname COLLATE utf8_danish_ci ASC
```

I get this result:

```
Økonomi
Downloads
Grafik
Transfers
```

But the correct way to order is like this:

```
Downloads
Grafik
Transfers
Økonomi
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if you put the `COLLATE` on the column instead of the sort?

Comment: @BartFriederichs How do you mean? I'm still a beginner! :)

Comment: you can add that collation also to your column definition. No idea if it works, but it is worth a shot. Also, I found that a certain version of MySQL has a bug in the collation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756666/is-this-a-mysql-sorting-bug

Comment: @BartFriederichs That I have already tried. Let me have a look at the link you have provided!

Comment: What database driver are you using? (I.e. MySQL, MySQLi, PDO, etc.)

Comment: I am using mysql. However I got it working! The last issue was that the letters in the mysql fields showed some code instead of the special ÆØÅ letters!

Answer (score 0):

It's being put in the ASCII order, since "0konomi" is after "Downloads" alphabetically.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY tagname
```

Comment: It would be nice for you, if you share a small amount of description too. It would help readers understand what you're trying to do.